# Adding Navigation Drawer to Top left

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, navigation

I want to add a navigation drawer to the top left of my screen with all the buttons in it so you can navigate through all the activity's while being on another.

I have no idea how to begin with this, can anyone give me a hand?

This is my code so far,
Main:

```
package com.example.rodekruis;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button6).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button7).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button8).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button9).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button10).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button10:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AfspraakActivity.class);
                break;
            case R.id.button8:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BezoekActivity.class);
                break;
            case R.id.button9:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactActivity.class);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MeningActivity.class);
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RouteActivity.class);
                break;
            case R.id.button1:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SpecialistenActivity.class);
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BWCActivity.class);
                break;
            case R.id.button6:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AgendaActivity.class);
                break;
            case R.id.button7:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NieuwsActivity.class);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

activity_main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Afspraak   maken" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Bezoek  tijden" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Contact" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=" Geef je mening!" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=" Route begeleiding" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Specialisten" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.03"
            android:text="Brandwonden centrum" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Agenda" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Nieuws" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Follow this link: http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

To create Navigation Drawer you need to use DrawerLayout as root of your view. please note gravity is responsible for alignment of Navigation Drawer.here it is given as start as you want to show on left.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

after this you can initialize listview with your buttons

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mButtonTitles))
```

once it is done define onclick listeners and open corresponding activities.

Comment: Thanks for reacting. Where in my activity do i need to put the above code? On top of the activity, on the bottom, or somewhere in the middle? I'm kind off new to this and if i put it on top i get errors

Comment: Inside onCreate() function as it is the first method which gets executed in Activity lifecycle.i will suggest you to got through Activity lifecycle and for further Navigation Drawer click below [link] (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)